# Magento REST API Response is not return from _create() method

Tags: magento-1.9, api, rest-api

I am working on **REST Api** for saving the data,

i am trying as like below data is saving but can't **return the response**

The below file `V1.php` `(model/Api2/Customer/Rest/Admin/V1.php)`

```
protected function _create($couponData)
{
    $websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore();

    Mage::log($websiteId,null,'website.log');
    Mage::log($store,null,'store.log');
    try {
          $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
          $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
                   ->setStore($store)
                   ->setFirstname($couponData['name'])
                   ->setLastname($couponData['name'])
                   ->setEmail($couponData['email'])
                   ->setPassword($couponData['pwd']);
          $cid = $customer->save();
          $cid = "1232";
          echo "-------"; print_r($cid); echo "-------";

       // $this->_retrieveCollection($cid);
        //$this->_loadSalesRule($cid);


        return "testt";

     } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo "---------Going To Expection---------";
        print_r(json_encode($e->getMessage()));

     }

     return "testtt1";

}
/**
 * Retrieve list of coupon codes.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function _retrieveCollection($cid)
{
   /* $ruleId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('rule_id');
    $rule = $this->_loadSalesRule($ruleId);
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/coupon_collection');
    $collection->addRuleToFilter($rule);
    $this->_applyCollectionModifiers($collection);
    $data = $collection->load()->toArray();
    //return $data['items'];*/
    return "----Recrive Collection Function---".$cid;
}
/**
 * Load sales rule by ID.
 *
 * @param int $ruleId
 * @return Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule
 */
protected function _loadSalesRule($ruleId)
{
   /* 
   if (!$ruleId) {
        $this->_critical(Mage::helper('salesrule')
            ->__('Rule ID not specified.'), Mage_Api2_Model_Server::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    $rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($ruleId);
    if (!$rule->getId()) {
        $this->_critical(Mage::helper('salesrule')
            ->__('Rule was not found123.'), Mage_Api2_Model_Server::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return $rule;
    */
    return "Hello";
}
```

}

I am sending **request with variable**

```
try {
$authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
$oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
$oauthClient->enableDebug();
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
    $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
    $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
    $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
    header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
    exit;
} else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
    $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
    $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
    $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
    $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
    header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
    exit;
} else {
    $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
    $ruleId = "3";
    $couponGenerationData = array();
    $couponGenerationData['name'] = "ramesh";
    $couponGenerationData['email'] = "ramesh.Restapi421@test.com";
    $couponGenerationData['pwd'] = "test123";

    /* Send Throught Post*/
    $resourceUrl = $apiUrl."/coupondemo/{$ruleId}";
    //$resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/coupondemo/rules/{$ruleId}/codes";
    $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, json_encode($couponGenerationData), OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST, array(
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ));
    // Retrieve list of created coupons via GET
    $collectionFilters = array('limit' => $couponGenerationData['qty'], 'order' => 'coupon_id', 'dir' => 'dsc');
    $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, $collectionFilters, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_GET, array(
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ));
    $coupons = json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponse(), true);
    // Display the newly generated codes to demonstrate that the Coupon AutoGen API works
    // In reality, you might put these codes in emails to customers, store them in a database, etc.
    echo "New coupon codes:<br/>";
    foreach ($coupons as $coupon) {
        echo " --> " . $coupon['code'] . "<br/>";
    }
}} catch (OAuthException $e) {
print_r($e->getMessage());
echo "<br/>";
print_r($e->lastResponse);
```

}

it' returning only **"Recrive Collection Function"**

Answer (score 0):

In my above script i am sending POST & GET requests at same time that's why i am getting response for GET because GET is the latest(last) request.

```
try {
   $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? 
      OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;

   $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, 
                    OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);

   $oauthClient->enableDebug();

   if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
        $requestToken = $oauthClient->
           getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
        header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' 
            . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
        exit;
 } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], 
        $_SESSION['secret']);
        $accessToken = $oauthClient->      
           getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
      exit;
     } else {
       $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], 
       $_SESSION['secret']);
       $ruleId = "3";
       $couponGenerationData = array();
       $couponGenerationData['name'] = "ramesh";
       $couponGenerationData['email'] = "ramesh.Restapi421@test.com";
       $couponGenerationData['pwd'] = "test123";

/* Send Throught Post*/
$resourceUrl = $apiUrl."/coupondemo/{$ruleId}";
//$resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/coupondemo/rules/{$ruleId}/codes";
$oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, json_encode($couponGenerationData), OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST, array(
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
));
$coupons = json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponse(), true);
// Display the newly generated codes to demonstrate that the Coupon AutoGen API works
// In reality, you might put these codes in emails to customers, store them in a database, etc.
echo "New coupon codes:<br/>";
foreach ($coupons as $coupon) {
    echo " --> " . $coupon['code'] . "<br/>";
     }
    }
  } catch (OAuthException $e) {
  print_r($e->getMessage());
  echo "<br/>";
  print_r($e->lastResponse);
}
```

Comment: any idea about this error ?  https://snag.gy/wTLXpx.jpg